# Numerical Analysis Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a question that I would just like a little bit of clarification about.

Find a and b, 0 < a  1, 0 < b  1 such that
max
x is element of [−1,1] |(x + b)(x + a)(x − a)(x − b)| = max x is element of [−1,1] |(x2 − a2)(x2 − b2)|
be as small as possible.

In class my teacher said that Si(x) = 2x(x^2-a^2) + 2x(x^2-b^2) = 0.

I know why we set it equal to zero but where does the left side of the equation come from? I cannot figure this out and would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Please check the question text again, it would help if you could make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the product rule.
Let f(x) = x^2 - a^2
g(x) = x^2 - b^2
Then
f'(x) = 2x
g'(x) = 2x
Thus
(f(x)g(x))' = 2x(x^2-a^2) + 2x(x^2-b^2)